# baseVariants in site definition with ports

Tags: typo3

I use docker on Mac OS X. On Mac OS X there is no possibility to map a domain name like mysite.local to something like http://localhost:8015/ etc.

So I have to call my docker container with http://localhost:8015/ The backend works as expected and shows me the applicationContext Development/Docker. The frontend works too,  but only when i use the base entry in site.config:

base: http://localhost:8015/

works but:

```
baseVariants: 
  - 
     base: http://localhost:8015/
     condition: 'applicationContext == "Development/Docker"'
```

does not.

Any ideas why or any workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: just stumbled upon https://ngrok.com/ today, it looks like it would work with mac. Could be important too if you use ddev or docker directly, but I don't have a mac, so I can't help in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i found the solution: it was a minor error in my configuration. In the htaccess file of my docker volume i wrote:

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development/Docker
```

this syntax is wrong but it works in the backend ... so TYPO3 showed me in the backend the context "Development/Docker". But it does not work in the frontend ... This syntax works:

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development/Docker
```

Now my baseVariants runs as expected.
Sorry for the noise ... :-)

Comment: please mark your answer as solution then